# Sonata Admin Bundle Error opening jQuery Dialog

Tags: jquery-ui, symfony, jquery-ui-dialog, symfony-sonata

I am creating a CMS with Symfony2 and SonataAdminBundle.

When I put this:

```
->add('tags', 'sonata_type_model', array('expanded' => true))
```

I get the + button but when I click the button I get JS error: "Object [object Object] has no method 'dialog'"

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Whats your Association mapping?
What happens if you only give ->add('tags')?
You may need 'sonata_type_collection' but need details to suggest.

Comment: If I put ->add('tags') I get a mutiple select with all the tags.  that's right...

Comment: Have you solved the "Object [object Object] has no method 'dialog'" problem? I have the same issue here with `->add('tags', 'sonata_type_model', array('expanded' => true, 'by_reference' => false, 'multiple' => true, 'required' => false))`.

Comment: I'm sorry but.. not :-(. Leaved Sonata and using Crud Symfony generator at the moment

Answer (score 0):

In my case the reason of this problem was included jquery file (jquery-2.0.2.min.js) after bundle script files.

Try to remove extra ui/jquery core files that loaded after sonata files:

```
        <script src="/bundles/sonatajquery/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/bundles/sonatajquery/jquery-ui-1.8.23.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/bundles/sonatajquery/jquery-ui-i18n.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I can't try if this works... I'm not using Sonata anymore... I appreciate your help